# producing .sdf file using DBContext class?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4.1

I am follwoing this tutorial  from

http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

No I have created this code:

```
using MvcApp2.Models;
using System.Data.Entity.Design.PluralizationServices;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;


namespace MvcApp2.Models
{    
        public class StudentContext : DbContext
        {
            public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }

            protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
            }
        }

}
```

and in my Web.config I have added this Connection string:

```
 <add name="StudentContext" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|Student.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
```

When I build my project,according to the tutorial, I should be expecting an SDF file in my appcode callded students

Comment: Have you created the `SchoolInitializer` and configured it?

Comment: I did not actually because it should work without it right?

Comment: OK i also did Scool initializer but no SDF yet....

Comment: Actually: the SDF file should be created in your **`app_data`** directory - not your `app_code` as you said...

Comment: Hi I am sorry. yes I was actually looking at my code and yes it is app_data. Bu thte problem was different.After running my project, I was not evern browsing to my controller and that is why it was not initiating any of my COntextDb logic. Now it is  working. Thank yo so much for your help:)